# Which axis property show whether the axis is visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to check whether an axis is visible or not. I thought perhaps the `'visible'` axis property would indicate this, but it doesn't seem like it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
print(ax.properties()['visible'])
ax.set_axis_off()
print(ax.properties()['visible'])
```

yields

```
True
True
```

How can I check whether an axis is visible or not? (Other than by eye.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to make an axis invisible to the eye, e.g. if you colorize all spines, ticks and labels white, you would also not see the axis, while it is still there.

If the question is how to check if the axis has been turned off, you may check

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
print(ax.axison)          # prints True
ax.set_axis_off()
print(ax.axison)          # prints False
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Thank you!